# In IDEA, how to auto remove .attach_pidxxx file

Tags: java, intellij-idea

After run Java test case (`TestNG` test, if it matters) in `IDEA`, a file named `.attach_pid<xxx>` (e.g *.attach_pid16153*) will be created, under project root.

They are still there even after test case finished.

And After a while, there will be a lot such files, and I have to remove them by hand.

**The questions is:**

- Is there a config to remove them automatically after the unit test or other type of run/debug terminated?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This file appears because of the [known Java bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8214300).

The bug is already fixed for Java 12.

JetBrains developers have [backported this fix](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JRE-1061) into JetBrains Runtime and the fix is delivered in [IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1 EAP version](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion/) (to be released in the end of March 2019).

Comment: @obvionaoe make sure IntelliJ IDEA is running on the bundled runtime: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544879.

Comment: The attach pid file stopped bugging me when I switched from corretto-21 to openjdk-21.